# How to bind width of child element to width of parent element in WinRT

Tags: .net, xaml, binding, windows-runtime

I have a ProgressBar in StackPanel. I want my ProgressBar to have the size of my StackPanel or a bit smaller.

**I tried** `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentElementName}"` but this doesn't actually work in WinRT

**Sample Code**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="120,15,0,0">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" 
             Value="{Binding ProgressPercent}"  
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             IsIndeterminate="False" 
             Maximum="100" 
             Height="10"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide path in binding.

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=parentElementName, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios where dynamic layouts etc. are used, **one may not know the name of the parent element**. In this case the following code can be used:

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Please note that I use this code in a Windows desktop app and not sure if it runs with WinRT.